# Javascript in asp.net masterpage head content seems not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using a ready made jquery date picker with ASP.NET text boxes. I'm also using MasterPage so here's what I've done so far -

**Page linked to Master Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<link href="overcast/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#txtBeginDate").datepicker();
        $("#txtEndDate").datepicker();
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

**Two text box controls**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBeginDate" runat="server"  Placeholder="Select Begin Date"></asp:TextBox> to 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server"  Placeholder="Select End Date" />
```

But when I place cursor into these text boxes, the date picker doesn't show.

Please advice.

Comment: have you checked for any js errors? are the paths specified correct?

Comment: @3nigma How to check for js errors?

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/  for FireFox or chrome it has its own set of developer tools

Comment: Use firebug console in firefox, dragonfly in opera etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default ASP WebForms generates a unique client id for each control which includes any parent ids. So the id may end up as something like "ct100_ct101_txtBeginDate".

Try using the Client ID with inline code like:

```
$("#<%= txtBeginDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Chris mentioned in his answer the generated ids could be different in ASP.Net web forms server controls, if you are using .net4 set the `ClientIDMode="Static"` that way you can use your own ids

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBeginDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  Placeholder="Select Begin Date"></asp:TextBox> to 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Placeholder="Select End Date" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As Chris said, the actual control ID will be a whole lot different when it is rendered. If you want to stick with JQuery, you can use the known part of the control ID, because it will always be at the end of the actual ID, as an [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$(function () {
        $("input[id$=txtBeginDate").datepicker();
        $("input[id$=txtEndDate").datepicker();
    });
```